# How to control Android based tablet from Windows or iMac desktop?

Tags: tablet, remote-access

I have a setup in office where on a desk is fixed samsung galaxy tablet on a stand. On the same desk I have Windows PC or iMac. Customer is looking at the tablet. I am the desktop user and I want to control tablet from my desktop to demo a website. Customer looking at tablet should not see any part of my desktop other than the website. Since the stand secures the ipad and hides home button on ipad, I want to be able to access the home button from my desktop to wake up ipad from sleeping.

What is the solution for above?

Answer (score 0):

Team viewer has a remote access program that can be hosted on Android.

[This guide](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/fully-control-your-android-device-from-any-computer-0164097/) has a free solution but I haven't tried it and I don't know if it'll unlock the device (it does specifically say it can do the home button).